# ¿Cómo eliminar archivos entre dos fechas determinadas?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, powershell

Estoy intentando crear un bat o una linea en powershell que haga esto.

En una carpeta determinada, eliminar archivos creados entre el 02 de Agosto del 2019 y el 06 de agosto del 2019.

probé con esto en PowerShell, pero me borra todos los archivos del 6 de agosto para arriba, no se como ponerlo

```
/p "D:\" /s /d 8/06/2019 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

Tambien vi esto en internet para crear un .bat

```
@echo off
echo ============INICIANDO PROCESO DE COPIADO=============
echo ......=ACCEDIENDO A LA CARPETA DE LOS ARCHIVOS=.......
W:
echo .....................................................
echo ==============EMPEZANDO COPIA DE ARCHIVO=============
set fecha=%date%
xcopy "D:" /d:%fecha% "D:\DestinoArchivo\*.rar"
echo .............=COPIA DE ARCHIVO TERMINADA=............
echo =====================================================
pause
```

Pero no me sirve porque necesito eliminarlo y el problema es, que necesito ingresar manualmente las fechas

```
@echo off 
echo copia realizada el %date% > c:\destino\resultado.log 
xcopy c:\origen\*.* c:\destino\*.* /D:%1 /f /c /y >> c:\destino\resultado.log
```

encontre que con el %1 puedo poner una fecha, pero para la segunda ?

Alguien me podria hechar una mano con un ejemplo o algo que yo pueda trabajar ?

Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente el `xcopy` solo puede listar los archivos desde una fecha y no por rango, por lo que estás limitado en este sentido, además de las limitaciones propias dle interprete DOS. Con Powershell es otra cosa, por ejemplo, para borrar archivos entre el 21/5 y 22/5 puedes hacer:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\origen\*.* | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt '05/21/2019' -AND $_.lastwritetime -lt '05/22/2019'} | Remove-Item
```

La fecha en formato americano y recuerda que juega también la hora por lo que si quieres listar un día completo el rango debe ser  `-gt fecha` (grather than) y `-lt fecha + 1día` (less than)

**Documentación adiconal:**

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6)
- [`Where-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6)
- [`Remove-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Amigo muchisimas gracias por responder,

Pero me aparece el siguiente error

At line:1 char:133
+ ... ct {$_.lastwritetime -gt '07/01/2019' -AND $_.las
+
You must provide a value expression following the '-' o
At line:1 char:134
+ ... {$_.lastwritetime -gt '07/01/2019' -AND $_.lastwr
+
Unexpected token 'lt' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], Pare
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

Comment: @OmarNoa Edite mi respuesta, había un `\n` que seguramente rompía el comando al pegarlo en una consola de powersell, pruebalo y cualquier cosa me dices

Comment: Mira, lo estoy copiando así:

Get-ChildItem D:\Serv_4_229_PRD\DECEVAL_PROD\2019\Julio\*.* | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt '07/01/2019' -AND $_.lastwritetime - lt '07/31/2019'} | Remove-Item

Y me sigue mandando el mismo error. 

Podrias decirme por favor que he hecho mal ?